# Javascript - sort documents in firestore, get data from them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a little problem regarding googles firestorage. I have data in my firestore sorted following way:

```
-chatrooms(collection)
    -chatroom1(document)
      -chatroom1(collection)
         -message1(document)
         -message2(document)
         -message3(document)
    -chatroom2
    -...
```

Every message is nothing else then a document formated the following way:

```
counter: integer
partner1: string
partner2: string
sender: string
value: string
```

My goal is to get the last chatmessage from each chatroom and store them in an array. I try following command for that:

```
lastmessage = await firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatkeys[i]}`).collection(`${chatkeys[i]}`).orderBy("counter").limit(1).get().then(
                querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        console.log(doc)
                    })
                }
            )
```

You see, I try to use orderBy and get the newest message out of all messages, also I limit it to 1 so I get only one result, the newest to be precise. After that I take the querySnapshot and want to pull out of the doc I get the "value" key (look above on how my message files are formated, they all have a "value" key, thats the chat message) but now I start to struggle.

As a result I get following code thats insanely long and I have no clue what is going on, I will show you a part of it:

```
"cP": e {
    "Qe": Map {
      "counter" => e {
        "Ne": 2,
        "Zt": 1,
      },
    },
    "ce": false,
    "converter": [Function anonymous],
    "hasCommittedMutations": false,
    "key": t {
      "path": e {
        "len": 4,
        "offset": 5,
        "segments": Array [
          "projects",
  ...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

Can someone explain what is going on and even better, tell me how I can acomplish my goal?
I would like to get only the "value" string out of the newest document. I fail to understand how I can use orderBy with getting data out of the filtered document.

Comment: How are you accessing the `value` key? You should be using `doc.data().value`, however it looks like you are just logging `doc`. Other than that your query seems fine.

Comment: @Aside it worked! If you want write this as your answer here and I can give you the green checkmark then. Had big difficulties understanding this queries, thx for your simple answer.

Comment: @Aside, your comment is very helpful for the OP. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Aside I just have one other problem now, maybe you can also help me with that. console.log() gives me the result I was searching for. On the other side, "return" gives me an undefined back. Also I tried to research that but solutions working for other people dont work for me, you have maybe an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Aside in the comments, change how you log the output and use `doc.data().value`:

```
querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.data().value)
})
```

Here's an additional [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs):

> A QuerySnapshot contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the docs property or enumerated using the forEach method. The number of documents can be determined via the empty and size properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a more appropriate solution here than the approved solution using `forEach` (meant to loop over an array of values) :

```
lastmessage = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("chatrooms")
  .doc(`${chatkeys[i]}`)
  .collection(`${chatkeys[i]}`)
  .orderBy("counter")
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(QuerySnapshot => 
    QuerySnapshot.docs[0].data()
  );
```

> A QuerySnapshot contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects
> representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as
> an array via the docs property

> docs: Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot>

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0